# Laravel - Page not found even that the Route exists

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404, exists

I have this route:

```
Route::get('/dashboard/tags/edit/{tag}','UsersController@editTagIndex');
```

and this is my form action:
`action="/dashboard/tags/edit/{{$tag->id}}" method="get"`

it gives me Page not found as there is no route !

I have tried: `php artisan route:list`

and the route exists

what makes no sense is I have another route :

`Route::get('/dashboard/posts/edit/{post}','UsersController@editPostIndex');`

and it works perfectly

Comment: Can you explain why you are using get for the form actions? And why do you not have a separate controller for posts and tags?

Comment: check the URL in page source

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I use one controller for admin I just named it UsersController for now, I'll change that later, and the get method here because I use post method with the same URL from the page that this route supposed to be calling

Comment: @DouwedeHaan I just started learning php and laravel like 5 days ago

Comment: @DsRaj every other Route works fine but this one is the problem I have another route that I have copied this from it and it works fine

Comment: Thanks for trying to help I just fixed it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there maybe this will do the trick:

```
action="{{ action('UsersController@editTagIndex', [tag => $tag_id]) }}"
```

Good Luck

Comment: Same problem page not found

Comment: are you sure that  function editTagIndex exist on your controller !

Comment: what is the url you get after submitting the form ?

Comment: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/tags/edit/7?_token=nMQUrgiZhNW53EjvKzYAOFJ3L5oHKlvKWZKPIYws`

Comment: One more think , try position your route  `Route::get('/dashboard/tags/edit/{tag}','UsersController@editTagIndex');` at first position  your route.php file

Comment: Thanks for trying to help I just fixed it myself :)

Comment: @AhmedSherif What was the problem ?

Comment: I just saw the comment now sorry, I put the problem above in separate answer, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should be a post request since you are submiting an edit function.

Comment: same not found page

Comment: Thanks for trying to help I just fixed it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had this function in my Tag Model

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

so instead of passing it $tag->id in the form action

I passed it $tag->name

Thank you all for trying to help